# Laravel & Dropzone.js file request

Tags: javascript, laravel, dropzone.js

In my controller when I try `dd($request->file('file'));` return null... Any solution please!

More Info, I upload only 1 image without Ajax request, using the submit button `autoProcessQueue: false` because I have others inputs that need validation. When I turn auto process to true just for testing the upload works fine but the the file request still null.

The view:

```
<form role="form" action="{{ route('user::products::store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

{!! csrf_field() !!}

<div class="image {{ $errors->has('thumbnail') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">

<div id="droparea">

<div class="message" data-dz-message>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span>
<p>Click or drag image here</p>
</div>

<div class="preview">
<div class="template">

<div class="thumb">
<img data-dz-thumbnail />
<span data-dz-remove class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove remove"></span>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</form>
```

Dropzone.js Config

```
<script>
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

var myDropzone = new Dropzone(document.body, 
{
    url: "/u/products/add",
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
    previewsContainer: ".preview",
    clickable: "#droparea",
    paramName : "file",
    acceptedFiles: "image/.jpeg,.jpg,.png",
    maxFilesize: 2,
    maxFiles: 1,
    thumbnailWidth: 150,
    thumbnailHeight: 150,
    headers: {
    'X-CSRF-Token': $('input[name="_token"]').val()
    }
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add a input field:

```
<input type="file" name="file" />
```

Comment: I don't need to use input! I use it as fallback for old browsers!

Comment: Try: Dropzone.autoDiscover = true;